# URL rewriting not working with iframe expressjs

Tags: node.js, iframe, express

I am trying to rewrite the URL of an iframe using [express](http://expressjs.com/).

Similar code works fine on files available in my `public` folder (which express knows about thanks to `server.use(express['static'](__dirname + '/public'`).

Jade code:

```
iframe(width="560", height="315", src="/videos/9bZkp7q19f0", frameborder="0", allowfullscreen=true)
```

Express code:

```
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (/videos/.test(req.url)) {
    req.url = req.url.replace("videos", "embed");
    req.url = "www.youtube.com" + req.url;
  }

  next();
});
```

Adding `console.log(req.url)` shows the correct url (www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0), yet express logs a 404 error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just change `req.url` and expect the client to actually retrieve data from there. What you need is either a proxy or a redirect.

A redirect will force the iframe to redirect to `youtube.com`:

```
res.redirect('http://www.youtube.com' + req.url.replace('videos', 'embed'));
```

A proxy will actually request the page from your server, download the content, and serve back to the client: (you can use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) for this)

```
req.pipe(require('request')('http://www.youtube.com' 
   + req.url.replace('videos', 'embed'))).pipe(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While redirecting is not an option, request is just what I needed.

Comment: @medimatrix no problem! You might need to play around with the request headers. Also check youtube's acceptable use policy just in case.